# I am getting incompatitble debugger version in eclipse while using pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

i get a incompatible debugger version in eclipse while using pydev my default port of the pydev debugger is 5678

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an old version of the debugger in your pythopath?

Please check your interpreter configuration and see if you didn't add it there by accident.